# Reading sql query and executing from file in db2 stored procedures

Tags: stored-procedures, db2

I am new to `db2` stored procedures.

I am looking to read a `SQL` file as a parameter and looking to execute that `SQL` query to get the records.

Can anyone help me with this?
thanks in advance.

Comment: Which operating-system runs your Db2-Server? (Z/OS,  i-Series, Linux/Unix/Windows)

Comment: in windows server   2012 r2

Comment: In Which programming language do you want to write your stored-procedure ? ( java,  c,  c++,  C#,  SQL PL,  or PL-SQL ) ?

Comment: trying to code in pl sql

Comment: What have you coded so far? Please include your code in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Use utl_file procedure to read file and build sql string. Use dynamic sql to execute sql string. Check following links for more details.

utl_file:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0053697.html

dynamic sql:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.plsql.doc/doc/c0053894.html